# Compiler errors when using a Boost::Thread with parameters

Tags: c++, boost

I would greatly appreciate any help here. I am trying to call a function asynchronously with Boost::Thread, but I am getting some errors. This is my real code.

In main:

```
vector<std::string> a = ...;
vector<std::string> b = ...;
vector<boost::thread> threads;

threads.push_back(boost::thread(do_work, an_integer, a[i], b.begin(), b.end()));

// Later I will join()...
```

Elsewhere:

```
void do_work(int i, std::string a_string, vector<string>::iterator begin, vector<string>::iterator end)
{
    // Some stuff
}
```

I am quite new to this stuff, being much more used to C#. Anyway, these are the errors I am getting:

```
error C2664: 'void (int,std::string,std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>,std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>' to 'int'

error C2664: 'void (int,std::string,std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>,std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>)' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' to 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>'

error C2664: 'void (int,std::string,std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>,std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>)' : cannot convert parameter 4 from 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>' to 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>'
```

I would greatly appreciate any help you could offer. I am almost certainly doing something extremely inane! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Looks like the error message doesn't match your code. Why don't you write a sample program to reproduce the error and post the full source code?

Comment: What is the definition of `an_integer`? The compiler seems to think it's an iterator rather than an `int`. Also, could you show the real code for defining `b` and the call to `threads.push_back()`? The compiler says that `b.begin()` and `b.end()` are different types, which can't be in the code you've listed here, which makes me think the code you've listed here isn't what you've fed the compiler.

Comment: I am really sorry everyone. Thank you very much for your help, but after reading your comments, I read my code more carefully. It turns out that I had accidentally defined b as a vector of vector of string, not a vector of string. After fixing that, all was well again. I would like to thank you both very much. @chrisaycock, since your answer was particularly helpful for me, if you create an answer, I will happily upvote it and mark it as the answer. Thanks again, to both of you, and sorry for this mistake. I tried so many different ways, and they all failed because of this bug! lol.

Comment: @niemiro I'm glad you found the error. I've massaged my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That compiler error says that `b.begin()` and `b.end()` are different types, which clearly can't be in the code you've listed. Recheck your code to make sure you haven't defined `b` to be something else. (Also check `an_integer` since the compiler believes it's an iterator.)